# Bypass cookie request for form submission

Tags: javascript, html

We're trying to secure our web site - is it possible for someone to bypass our site's requirement for cookies when submitting forms?
We're trying to prevent cross site attacks.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean **Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)**. This can be easily prevented with a special CSRF token in your form.

The token should be different every time the form gets displayed.

```
<?php 
    $token = md5(time()); /* a simple attempt to generate a token */ 
    $_SESSION['csrf_token'] = $token;
?>
```

Include it in your form.

```
<form> 
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<?php echo $token ?>"> 
    ...
</form>
```

And verify it on the server on form submittion.

```
<?php
    $storedToken = $_SESSION['csrf_token'];
    unset($_SESSION['csrf_token']); 
    if ($_POST['csrf_token'] == $storedToken) { ... } 
?>
```

**Make sure the token can only be used exactly once.**

Also **use SSL** to improve security if not already in place.

Comment: Thanks - What's to stop someone creating a bot that automatically takes the token and responds?

Comment: That's were captcha's are for and a different problem. Your concern was "cross site attacks". If a bot submits the form it's not cross site. **Everyone with access to the form can submit it**.